# SQL In Memory OLTP wont Release RAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table in RAM that is Schema durability only. I do a lot of transactions on this table and its footprint keeps growing. After every transaction i wipe this table out and unfortunately it does not release the RAM till I get memory pressure and even then it does not completely clear out. This is causing me to receive out of memory in this pool errors. I've tried forcing garbage collection but that does not seem to be solving this situation. Any ideas what to do? An empty table should not be taking up 4 gb of RAM....

Comment: Any idea what references i should be looking for? Right now it is telling me that table is 1.7GB but the Index is 6 GB. The assigned values keep fluctuating. Its the most bizare thing ever.

Comment: I am confused. I created the tables via a regular script because I want them to exist. And i don't have variables that reference these tables in my sql job. I do reference them in a different stored procedure where i do a join on them but other than that they are regular tables to me. Am i misunderstanding how to use the Schema only tables?

Comment: oops im sorry i misunderstood you. I was thinking dotnet in stead of sql server. Forget my prior comments